# Cannot combine two site's pages together

Tags: migration

I am having some strange difficulties in exporting some pages from one wordpress site (site 1) to another (site 2).

I exported the xml from site 1 with Tools > Export

I imported the xml from site 1 into site 2 with Tools > Import.

The re-assign authors goes fine, until I get to the last page. 
Error messages abound; "Media "___" Already exists", "Invalid post type", "Failed to import ____".

The last thing said is "The link you have followed has expired." I had just made the file 10 minutes ago.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1: Failed to import -> It must be some plugins not activated and demo is not imported.

2: Media already exist is of course media file is already there.

3: You need to increase PHP max execution time for this. Also how much is your demo import file size?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "Demo import file size"?

Comment: Demo means that your exported XML.